# @OnTimer not triggering after window

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been playing around with Apache Beam's Timers but can't manage to trigger them.

As far as I know, you define a Timer the following way inside a DoFn.

```
@TimerId("expiry")
private final TimerSpec expirySpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);
```

I've chosen `TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME` as my events don't have a timestamp assigned and would like to trigger the execution of the Timer as soon as windows finish.

```
        .apply(
             "FixedWindow",
            Window.<KV<String, GenericRecord>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                .triggering(AfterProcessingTime
                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                .accumulatingFiredPanes()
        )
        .apply("ExecuteAfterWindowFn", ParDo.of(new ExecuteAfterWindowFn()));
```

I would expect the following timer, which is inside a DoFn that basically accumulates objects within a buffer and after the window is done go on with the pipeline and process the set of events...

```
        @OnTimer("expiry")
    public void onExpiry(
        OnTimerContext context,
        @StateId("bufferedSize") ValueState<Integer> bufferedSizeState,
        @StateId("buffered") BagState<GenericRecord> bufferedState) throws IOException {
        flush(context, bufferedState, bufferedSizeState);
    }
```

...to be executed successfully. Am I missing something or not understanding how Timers work in Apache Beam?

Answer (score 0):

You can check[1] where there are examples of timer usages.

You will need to set when timers should fire[2], where might be the place that has missed.

[1] https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html

[2] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/Timer.java#L53